# Can I disable click events for polygons loaded from a kml while maintaining them for markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, php-5.3

in my web app I am loading a kml file to the map - this works fine
in the same kml file (dynamically generated from php) I have some logic that checks if there are records returned from the DB if not it generates a kml polygon instead of placemarks

what I would like to do is make the polygon click events disabled while still allowing the markers/placemarks to trigger click events.

is this possible or will I have to load the polys to a separate kml layer?

https://maps.google.com/?q=http://biasigns.com/pdo_xmlgen09.php?city_id=5 the kml file 
to see the polygon logic happening change the city_id to 8

I can paste all the code but am not sure its necessary to answer. let me know if you need to see more.

Comment: How will you be displaying the KML?  [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) as the link you posted, or [KmlLayer in the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `<name>` from the polygon (as well as the `<description>`), infowindows will be suppressed on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fpdo_xmlgen09_city_id8_noName.kml&hl=en&ll=34.083872,-117.407198&spn=0.052959,0.076218&sll=33.936518,-116.98142&sspn=0.053051,0.076218&t=m&z=14) and on the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/pdo_xmlgen09_city_id8_noName.kml) (but you might want the name).

Comment: For my application that is the perfect solution i will not need to see the description or name thank you